# In typescript, why isn't it possible to initialize a class property by calling a method?

Tags: typescript, methods, constructor

The following typescript code works as expected but typescript throws a TS2564 error on the test2 and test3 properties. Is it because they are initialized inside of methods? How should a class like this be written.

I believe it works as expected because it is valid in javascript. Could it be caused by wrong typescript settings?

```
class class1{

    test1:number;//test1 is initialized as expected
    test2:number;//Property 'test2' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
    test3:number;//Property 'test3' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

    constructor(){
        //test1 
        this.test1 = 0;

        //test2
        const setTest2To0 = () =>{
            this.test2 = 0;
        };
        setTest2To0();

        //test3
        this.setTest3To0();
    }

    setTest3To0(){
        this.test3 = 0;
    }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not track `this` mutations in this case.

However, there is a workaround. You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) pattern for declaring `test2` property.

```js
class class1 {

    test1: number;//test1 is initialized as expected
    test2: number;// ok
    test3: number;//Property 'test3' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

    constructor() {
        //test1 
        this.test1 = 0;

        //test2
        (() => {
            this.test2 = 0;
        })();

        //test3
        this.setTest3To0();
    }

    setTest3To0() {
        this.test3 = 0;
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed, TS is able to figure out that `test2` is initialized in `constructor`.

Please keep in mind that typescript is about static validation.

> So it is impossible to use setTest3To0 to initialize Test3?

Yes. You should use `test3: number | undefined`. Or you can use another syntax:

```js
class class1 {
    static getTest3() {
        return 0
    }

    constructor(public test1 = 0, public test2 = 0, public test3 = class1.getTest3()) { }

}
```

If you use `public` keyword there is no need to declare all your properties as you did before. As you might have noticed I have used static method for setting `test3` during class initialization.

Comment: So it is impossible to use setTest3To0 to initialize Test3?

Answer (score 3):

Since TypeScript 2.7 you can use the [definite assignment assertion modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) which means adding an exclamation mark between the variable name and the colon:

```
test3!: number
```

This has the same effect as adding a `// @ts-ignore TS2564` comment above it, and is you telling TS that you are definitely assigning it through all possible code execution paths through the constructor.